# A big ng-repeat to display the progress of builds

Tags: html, angular.js

I'm looking to improve the speed my `ng-repeat` or find an alternative way to do it, because it takes too long to load when it has to manage a lot of data.

```
    <div  class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-lg-2 block animate"
      ng-repeat="build in buildsRunning.builds.build | limitTo:totalDisplayed  track by build._id "
      ng-hide="build.hide"
     ng-class="getClasses(build._status,build._running)">
    <div class="title-container animate" >
        <p>{{::build._buildTypeId}}</p>
        <p class="running-on">Running on: <span class="agent">{{::build.agent._name}}</span></p>
        <p class="running-on">Version: <span class="agent">{{::build._number}}</span></p>
        <p class="running-on" ng-if="::build.user._name">Run by: {{::build.user._name}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="update-container animate col-xs-12">
        <div class="progress progress-running">
            <div class="progress-bar "
                 role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="{{build._percentageComplete}}" aria-valuemin="0"
                 aria-valuemax="100" style="width:{{build._percentageComplete}}%"
                 ng-class="{'progress-bar-success': build._percentageComplete > 5  ,'progress-bar-warning': build._percentageComplete <= 6}">
                    <span ng-if="build._percentageComplete > 5" class="sr-only"> {{build._percentageComplete}}% Completed
                        <p class="elapsed-time" ng-if="build._percentageComplete >= 50"> in : {{build.timeInfo}} Minutes</p>
                    </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: How many items are you displaying? In any case you should look at the profiler and AngularJS statistics for number of watched expressions and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is performance you are after, the [scroll till you drop directive by Angular UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-utils/#/scrollfix) may help.

A common mistake is to throw too many array members inside your DOM via `ng-repeat`, but you are already limiting your input...

You may consider using custom filter instead and making sure it is fast.